# How do you remove a static middleware on a post request?

Tags: go, go-gin

I want the home page to stop being available after a post request.
Here is my code.
Thanks in advance.

```
package main
import(
    "github.com/gin-contrib/static"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
   r := gin.Default()
   r.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("./pages/home", true)))
   r.POST("/example", func(c *gin.Context) {
      //here I would like to stop serving the static files on a POST request
   })
   r.Run(":8080")
}
```

My directory structure

```
-main.go
-pages
   -home
      -index.html
```

Comment: Do you know that your middleware (static file serve) causing infinite redirects?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean.

Comment: I run your code and browsers tell me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: it works for me, have you made and placed a file a pages directory - I have added the directory structure to make it more clear

Comment: I already created the pages directory and `home` file under it as shown in your code. When I visit `http://localhost:8080` it redirects forever. I `go get` the latest versions of the libraries. In your directory structure it has index.html but not in your code.

Comment: sorry i made a mistake in the directory tree. you have to make the folders and files as they are not made when adding libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert on `gin` but it is similar to `echo` so I created a snippet for you to check if it fits your needs.

It looks like it is not possible to detach middleware after attached [as discussed here](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/776), so my way is to check a global variable for each request to see if the resource is available.

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "sync/atomic"

    "github.com/gin-contrib/static"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

// using atomic package instead of using mutexes looks better in this scope
var noIndex int32

func indexMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    hdl := static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("./pages/home", true))
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        if atomic.LoadInt32(&noIndex) == 0 {
            hdl(c)
            // if you have additional middlewares, let them run
            c.Next()
            return
        }
        c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusBadRequest)
    }
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(indexMiddleware())
    r.POST("/example", func(c *gin.Context) {
        atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&noIndex, 0, 1)
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "OK")
    })
    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

Comment: That works for all request so after that first post you cannot connect and receive the html file.

Comment: Yes, all requests are satisfied until a post request to /example end point.

Comment: Is it possible only to stop requests to certain users

Comment: @JosephGlynn Yes it is possible of course if you have an authentication mechanism. You should know who made the request. HTTP protocol is stateless so, you should be able know clients somehow, e.g. headers, cookies, url parameters, etc. Please check basic http authentication and session management for gin.